# How ensure subprocess is killed on timeout when using `run`?

Tags: python, subprocess, kill-process

I am using the following code to launch a subprocess :

```py
# Run the program
subprocess_result = subprocess.run(
                cmd,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                check=False,
                timeout=timeout,
                cwd=directory,
                env=env,
                preexec_fn=set_memory_limits,
            )
```

The launched subprocess is also a Python program, with a shebang.
This subprocess may last for longer than the specified `timeout`.
The subprocess does heavy computations and write results in a file and does not contain any signal handler.

According to the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run, `subprocess.run` kills a child that timesout :

> The timeout argument is passed to Popen.communicate(). If the timeout
> expires, the child process will be killed and waited for. The
> TimeoutExpired exception will be re-raised after the child process has
> terminated.

When my subprocess timesout, I always receive the `subprocess.TimeoutExpired` exception, but from time to time the subprocess is not killed, hence still consuming resources on my machine.

So my question is, am I doing something wrong here ? If yes, what and if no, why do I have this issue and how can I solve it ?

Note : I am using Python 3.10 on Ubuntu 22_04

Comment: @S.B My script does some heavy computations and write the results in a file, without any signal handler. And no, unfortunately I have not been able to identify under what circumstances the script is still running after the timeout. Does your comment suggests that my understanding of the doc is correct, hence the child process should be killed in theory ?

Comment: What *could* be happening is that your subprocess is actually spawning a separate process to perform computations. `subprocess.run` will kill the child, but the grandchildren will be inherited by `1`. This is impossible to diagnose without seeing the actual process you are running, however given what you are saying (that these are "heavy computations") it seems likely that multiprocessing is in place.

Comment: The way to fix this is to either modify your child process to accept signals to perform a proper cleanup, or to write a wrapper script that will simply receive the signal, kill all its descendants, and then die

Comment: Thank you for the comments @Bakuriu I'll look on that side, but the true thing is that subprocesses are not mine :) And I think that some of them are not killed even if they do not launch subprocesses again, but I need to check that.

Comment: @ManuelSelva Okay. Looking at the source code for [`subprocess.run`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/subprocess.py#L506) it uses the [`.kill()` method on timeout](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/subprocess.py#L552) which [sends `SIGKILL`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/subprocess.py#L2157) which [cannot be handled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.SIGKILL). So I believe in your case you can't really do much about this. Don't use `timeout` and implement the timeout some other way

Comment: @Bakuriu if the subprocess does not launch any other process, it should work, isnt'it ?

Comment: @ManuelSelva You can see from the source code of `subprocess.run` that I linked above that if you see the `TimeoutException` it means the `child` was `.kill()`ed and `SIGKILL` cannot be ignored by processes, so the **direct** child is certainly dead... but granchildren may still be running. Note that for example [`multiprocessing` has a daemon flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon) that is meant to handle this kind of cases, where you spawn a subprocess but you want to make sure that you can clean up all its descendants.

Comment: @Bakuriu got it. Thank you again for your help. Do you mind writing an answer so that I can accept it or do you think this does not deserve a question on its own ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely culprit for the behaviour you see is that the subprocess you are spawning is probably using multiprocessing and spawning its own child processes. Killing the parent process does **not** automatically kill the whole set of descendants. The granchildren are inherited by the `init` process (i.e. the process with PID `1`) and will continue to run.

You can verify from the source code of [`suprocess.run`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/subprocess.py#L548) :

```
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    try:
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
    except TimeoutExpired as exc:
        process.kill()
        if _mswindows:
            # Windows accumulates the output in a single blocking
            # read() call run on child threads, with the timeout
            # being done in a join() on those threads.  communicate()
            # _after_ kill() is required to collect that and add it
            # to the exception.
            exc.stdout, exc.stderr = process.communicate()
        else:
            # POSIX _communicate already populated the output so
            # far into the TimeoutExpired exception.
            process.wait()
        raise
    except:  # Including KeyboardInterrupt, communicate handled that.
        process.kill()
        # We don't call process.wait() as .__exit__ does that for us.
        raise
```

Here you can see [at line 550](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/subprocess.py#L550) the timeout is set on the `communicate` call, if it fires [at line 552 the subprocess is `.kill()`ed](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/subprocess.py#L552). [The `kill` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/subprocess.py#L2157) sends a [`SIGKILL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.SIGKILL) which immediately kills the subprocess without any cleanup. It's a signal that cannot be caught by the subprocess, so it's not possible that the child is somehow ignoring it.

The `TimeoutException` is then re-raised [at line 564](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/subprocess.py#L564), so if your parent process sees this exception the subprocess is already dead.

This however says nothing of granchildren processes. Those will continue to run as children of PID 1.

I don't see any way in which you can customize how `subprocess.run` handles subprocess termination. For example, if it used `SIGTERM` instead of `SIGKILL` you could modify your child process or write a wrapper process that will catch the signal and properly kill all its descendants. But `SIGKILL` doesn't give you this luxury.

So I believe that for your use case you cannot use the `subprocess.run` facade but you should use `Popen` directly. You can look at the `subprocess.run` implementation and take just the things that you need, maybe dropping support for platforms you don't use.

---

Note: There are extremely rare situations in which the subprocesses won't die immediately on SIGKILL. I *believe* the only situation in which this happens is if the subprocess is performing a very long system call or other kernel operation, which might not be interrupted immediately. If the operation is in deadlock this might prevent the process from terminating forever. However I don't think that this is your case, since you did not mention that the process is stuck doing nothing, but from what you said the process simply seems to continue running.